# Quartz within Spring xml or standard alone Quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

Having been struggling with quartz and spring integration, specially in the context of webpshere jndi lookup, the final solution I have is to use spring to define job and still need some property defined in quartz.properties.

Heard some strong opinion that using quartz inside spring will create strong dependency between them, We are new to quartz . Going forward, would like to make decision: Quartz defined in spring xml, or simple quartz properties file. Would really like to hear everyone's  input on it.

Answer (score 0):

I find nothing wrong in using both `quartz.properties` and Spring configuration. [Personally I keep](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/configuring-quartz-with-jdbcjobstore-in.html) static configuration that will unlikely ever change in a file and *dynamic* paramters (like thread pool size) in Spring configuration.

You can define jobs in any way you want - using Quartz fluent API, with `Scheduler` API, using XML scheduling plugin (not related to Spring) or via Spring configuration. It's up to you.

> using quartz inside spring will create strong dependency between them

No idea where such opinions are coming from. Basically Spring allows you to start/stop the scheduler automatically - without Spring you need to use some servlet listener or other odd workaround. With Spring scheduler is just one of your beans. There is absolutely no dependency. Spring adds some clever support, like the ability to schedule running arbitrary method of any bean, but there is no coupling between the two.

If your application is Spring-based, go for Spring integration, it works good.